# Firestore large Collections and Documents optimization

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database containing several `Collections`, but one will become potentially huge since it is recording measures on a long term, meaning potentially millions of `Documents`.

The requests to retrieve those `Documents` can be quite long that's why I wonder if a change as the following will help a little or not all.

Right now I have for example a document with this data:

```
timestamp: string
start_datetime: string
end_datetime: string
network_provider: string
```

If I change for example with the following format, will it help?

```
ts: string
start: string
end: string
np: string
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to provide a conclusive answer, but: *if* the slow performance that you perceive is caused by the bandwidth it takes to download the data, then yes that can be improved by using shorter field names. How much of an improvement that'll make depends on many factors that we can't know anything about though, so I recommend making the change on a small subset of your data and measuring its impact.

Comment: If you'll be able to provide more info, maybe we'll be able to help.